Populating Dropdown Menus For Ultimate Members Plugin Using the Choices Callback with an External API
I’m trying to create dynamic dropdown fields using the Ultimate Members plugin. I’ve managed to use the US Census api to create two drop down menus for a registration form that populates a states menu, and a county menu that gets the counties available for each state. Everything works fine in the registration form, the problem is that when the user submits the registration form the county name that is sent to the admin email for account approval is empty(the state value is being sent correctly.
I would appreciate it if somebody could point out where I went wrong. I’m using the choices callback feature and have added the following code to my themes functions.php file:
function custom_state_choices_callback() {
// Fetch states from U.S. Census Bureau API
$states_url = 'https://api.census.gov/data/2019/pep/population?get=NAME...';
$response = wp_remote_get($states_url);
$body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
$data = json_decode($body, true);
// Initialize an empty array for states
$states = array();
// Populate the states array
if (!empty($data) && is_array($data)) {
foreach ($data as $index =\> $state) {
if ($index === 0) continue; // Skip the header row
$state_code = $state\[1\];
$state_name = $state\[0\];
$states\[$state_code\] = $state_name;
}
}
return array_unique($states);
}

// Function to populate the county dropdown based on the selected state function
custom_county_choices_callback($has_parent = false) {
// Initialize an empty array for counties
$counties = array();
// Get the selected state from the parent field
if ($has_parent) {
// Get the selected state from the parent field
$parent_options = isset($\_POST\['parent_option'\]) ? $\_POST\['parent_option'\] : array();
if (!is_array($parent_options)) {
$parent_options = array($parent_options);
}
// Fetch counties for each selected state
foreach ($parent_options as $state_code) {
$counties_url = "https://api.census.gov/data/2019/acs/acs5?get=NAME&for=county:*&in=state:$state_code";
$response = wp_remote_get($counties_url);
$body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
$data = json_decode($body, true);
if (!empty($data) && is_array($data)) {
foreach ($data as $index =\> $county) {
if ($index === 0) continue; // Skip the header row
$county_name = explode(',', $county\[0\])\[0\];
$counties\[$county_name\] = $county_name;
}
}
}
}
// Optional: Display this if there are no related options for this choice
if (empty($counties)) {
$counties\[''\] = 'No counties found';
}
return array_unique($counties);
}

// Hook the functions to Ultimate Member's Choices Callback
add_filter('um_custom_field_choices_callback', function($choices, $field) {
if ($field\['meta_key'\] === 'service_state') {
$choices = custom_state_choices_callback();
} elseif ($field\['meta_key'\] === 'service_county') {
$choices = custom_county_choices_callback(true);
}
return $choices;
}, 10, 2);````



TIA

I initially tried creating a custom plugin and using JavaScript to populate the dropdown menus. Everything works in the registration form, but the state and county values were empty in the email that's sent to the admin.

I tried another approach and used the Callback Choices feature and made it one step further with the state value being sent to the admin email, but the county value that's sent to the admin is still empty.

